# Normalize 2 javascript arrays to look the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem with getting two 2D arrays to look alike.
The arrays look like this:

```
groupedObjects: [
    { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }, 
    { value: 100, currency: "USD" }, 
    {value: 320, currency: "RON" }
]
groupedObjects1: [
    { value: 500, currency: "EUR" }, 
    { value: 280, currency: "RON" }
]
```

or

```
groupedObjects: [
    { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }

]
groupedObjects1: [
    { value: 500, currency: "EUR" }, 
    { value: 280, currency: "RON" }
]
```

or

```
groupedObjects: [
    { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }
]
groupedObjects1: [
    { value: 500, currency: "EUR" }
]
```

or

```
groupedObjects: [
    { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }
]
groupedObjects1: [
]
```

The arrays could be of any size, with unlimited currencies, but not always equal as length.
How can I have those 2 arrays look identical? In case if one array does not include one currency, I would like that the array would have an element with {value: 0, currency: 'missing currency'} and all currencies in both arrays must be arranged in ascending order, sorted by currency

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Later edit:
The code I tried looks like:

```
                        if ($(groupedObjects).length > $(groupedObjects1).length) {
                            var newArray = [];
                            $.each(groupedObjects, function (key, value) {
                                var flag = false;
                                var breakout = false;
                                flag = (function () {
                                    $.each(groupedObjects1, function (key1, value1) {
                                        if (value.currency === value1.currency) {
                                            newArray.push(value1);
                                            breakout = true;
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                    });
                                    if (!breakout) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })();
                                if (flag) {
                                    newArray.push({
                                        value: 0,
                                        currency: value.currency
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            groupedObjects1 = newArray;
                        } else if ($(groupedObjects).length < $(groupedObjects1).length) {
                            var newArray = [];
                            $.each(groupedObjects1, function (key, value) {
                                var flag = false;
                                var breakout = false;
                                flag = (function () {
                                    $.each(groupedObjects, function (key1, value1) {
                                        if (value.currency === value1.currency) {
                                            newArray.push(value1);
                                            breakout = true;
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                    });
                                    if (!breakout) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })();
                                if (flag) {
                                    newArray.push({
                                        value: 0,
                                        currency: value.currency
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            groupedObjects = newArray;                          
                        } else if ($(groupedObjects).length == $(groupedObjects1).length) {
                            var newArray = [];
                            var oldArray = [];
                            oldArray = groupedObjects;
                            console.info('>>> Initial object 1');
                            console.info(groupedObjects);

                            $.each(groupedObjects1, function (key, value) {
                                var flag = false;
                                var breakout = false;
                                flag = (function () {
                                    $.each(groupedObjects, function (key1, value1) {
                                        if (value.currency === value1.currency) {
                                            newArray.push(value1);
                                            breakout = true;
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (!breakout) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })();
                                if (flag) {
                                    newArray.push({
                                        value: 0,
                                        currency: value.currency
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            //groupedObjects = newArray;        
                            $.merge(groupedObjects, newArray);

                            var newArray = [];
                            $.each(oldArray, function (key, value) {
                                var flag = false;
                                var breakout = false;
                                flag = (function () {
                                    $.each(groupedObjects1, function (key1, value1) {
                                        if (value.currency === value1.currency) {
                                            newArray.push(value1);
                                            breakout = true;
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (!breakout) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })();
                                if (flag) {
                                    newArray.push({
                                        value: 0,
                                        currency: value.currency
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            groupedObjects1 = newArray;
                            //$.merge(groupedObjects1, newArray);                                                               
                        }
```

Comment: the method should be only in jquery/javascript

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Why is that? I have tried a jQuery code, but I do not know how tu put it as a comment

Comment: if both arrays have same currency then it would be perfect, the code would have to do nothing, the arrays are allready normalized. In fact, I am doing a difference between groupedObjects and groupedObjects1, and that is the reason for the question

Comment: How can I put my jQuery code inside a comment?

Comment: edit your post and put it there

Comment: The edit option is not active, only share and delete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what's your final goal, but here's an example:

```
var arr1 = [
        { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }, 
        { value: 100, currency: "USD" }, 
        { value: 320, currency: "RON" }
    ],
    arr2 = [
        { value: 500, currency: "EUR" }, 
        { value: 280, currency: "RON" }
    ];


var appendMissingCurrencies = (function () {

    return function (dest, source) {
        //Use an object map for quick lookups
        var existingCurrenciesMap = currencyMapFrom(dest);

        source.forEach(function (item) {
            var currency = item.currency,
                currencyMissing = !existingCurrenciesMap[currency];

            if (currencyMissing) {
                existingCurrenciesMap[currency] = true;
                appendMissingCurrency(dest, currency);
            }
        });
    };

    function appendMissingCurrency(currencies, currency) {
        currencies.push({ value: 0, currency: currency });
    }

    function currencyMapFrom(currencies) {
        return currencies.reduce(function (map, item) {
            if (!map[item.currency]) map[item.currency] = true;
            return map;
        }, {});
    }
})();

function sortCurrencies(currencies) {
    return currencies.sort(function (a, b) {
        var currencyOrder = a.currency < b.currency? -1 : +(a.currency > b.currency);

        return currencyOrder? currencyOrder : a.value - b.value;
    });
}

appendMissingCurrencies(arr1, arr2);
appendMissingCurrencies(arr2, arr1);

arr1 = sortCurrencies(arr1);
arr2 = sortCurrencies(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `currency` is the driving force behind the desired algorithm. The first step is to find the common `set` of currencies between the two arrays and sort it.

```
container.currencies = (function(){
  var array = [];
    var func = function(arrayKey){ return function(key,value){
      array.push(value.currency);
      container.map[arrayKey][value.currency] = value.value;
   }
  };    
  $.each(a, func('a'));
  $.each(b, func('b'));

  return array.filter(function(elem, pos) {
                return array.indexOf(elem) == pos;
           }).sort()
})();
```

At the same time we are determining the unique set of currencies, we are also building up a contextual data mapping -- `container` holds the data context and `a` / `b` represent the original arrays and are also used as a property key under which each original arrays contents are stored.
If empty `container` would look like: `{map: {a:{}, b:{}}, currencies:[]}`

Once our data context is built, we need to roll it back out into arrays.

```
container.getNormalizedArrays = function(){
    var arrays = {a: [], b: []};
    function normalizer(target, currency){
      var value = container.map[target][currency]
      arrays[target].push({value: value?value:0, currency: currency}) 
    }

    $.each(container.currencies, function(key, value){
     normalizer('a', value);
     normalizer('b', value);
    })
    return arrays;
}
```

Check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/w57N5/) for full working example.